# Why can tensorflow use multithread while python can only execute one thread at a time due to GIL?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm wondering why we can have Tensorflow [run in a multi-thread fashion](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#optimizing_for_cpu) while python can only execute one thread at a time due to [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?

Comment: Python scripts can launch child processes to do their processing for them, thus achieving multi-processing without regular Python threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIL's restriction is slightly more subtle: only one thread at a time can be *executing Python bytecode*.

Extensions using Python's C API (like `tensorflow`) can release the GIL if they don't need it. I/O operations like using files or sockets also tend to release the GIL because they generally involve lots of waiting.

So threads executing extensions or waiting for I/O can run while another thread is executing Python bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the `tensorflow` core is written in `C++` and the python APIs are just the wrappers around it. While running the `C++` code regular python restrictions do not apply.